# Pyhonでスクレイピングした結果が表示されない

Tags: python, web-scraping

仮想環境にてPythonでのスクレイピングの勉強をしています。参考にしているのは「Pythonクローリング&スクレイピング」です。

コードをそのまま写して実行しているのですが結果が出力されません。エラーは出ずに通っているのでコードに問題は無いと思いますが、何も出力されないのはなぜでしょうか。[以前質問させていただいた時](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/74447/19110)の修正点は改善できているので全く解決策がわからず困っています。

```
from typing import Iterator
import requests
import lxml.html

def main():
  response = requests.get('https://gihyo.jp/dp')
  urls = scrape_list_page(response)
  for url in urls:
    print(url)

def scrape_list_page(response: requests.Response) -> Iterator[str]:
  html = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text)
  html.make_links_absolute(response.url)
  for a in html.cssselect('#listBook > li > a[itemprop="url"]'):
    url = a.get('href')
    yield url

if __name__ == '__name__':
  main()
```

本来ならば以下の行に続けてURLが表示されるようです。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
(scraping) vagrant@ubuntu-bionic:/vagrant$ python python_crawler_2.py
```

Comment: おそらく質問欄に書き写す際のミスかと思うのですが、`if __name__ == '__name__':` は `if __name__ == '__main__':` としないとコードが実行されません。

Comment: 参考までに、[サポートページ:Pythonクローリング&スクレイピング\[増補改訂版\] -データ収集・解析のための実践開発ガイドー:|技術評論社](https://gihyo.jp/book/2019/978-4-297-10738-3/support) で当該書籍に記載されているコードが配布されています。